# Android 2.2+ SDK - Properties file in /config not overriding file in .jar

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-2.2-froyo

I've had this problem with log property files before, but was able to re-bundle the jar (it was my own lib).  Now I have a .jar in which the default setup.properties file is bundled with it (and needed), and in a normal java project, I can put a setup.properties in /config and override the bundled one.  With Android, though, I'm getting an error:

```
[2011-03-10 14:39:35 - MyAndroid] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: setup.properties
Origin 1: /Users/me/Desktop/svn/ANDROID/MyAndroid/MyAndroid/config/setup.properties
Origin 2: /Users/me/Desktop/svn/ANDROID/MyAndroid/MyAndroid/lib/generic-library.jar
```

How do I configure this?